# Left Click - looping while detecting click

Tags: c++

Basically, the code below detects "U" is clicked, and if it's clicked then it checks for the left mouse button being clicked. It works up until that point, say you open it, gives it a click per second value, click 'u', and left-click. After you hold the left click it sends left clicks at the desired speed, but it doesn't stop until you click escape. I need it to stop once you let go of the left click button. I've tried a few different things all of which ending up with it either only sending 2 clicks or just not working. TLDR - need it to detect on key, then if the left click button is held down, sends the clicks at the desired cps, and when you let go of left click it stops clicking. I know it worded terribly, English isn't my first language. `bool bClick = false;`

```cpp
while (true)
{
  //toggles it on and off
  if (GetAsyncKeyState('U') & 1)
    bClick = !bClick;
  if (bClick)
  {
    while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)
    {
      while (1)
      {

        INPUT input[2] = {};

        input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
        input[0].mi.dx = x;
        input[0].mi.dy = y;
        input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

        input[1] = input[0];
        input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

        SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));

        std::cout << "Clicked ";
        std::cout << clicks++;
        std::cout << " times \n";
        Sleep(1000 / cps);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
        {
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your program will continuously send click messages when running on my computer, and it will not stop by pressing the'U' or Esc key.
(I’m not sure if your problem is that the special button cannot be detected or the click is not issued)

Comment: The code listed will stop on escape for me, but I dont know how to get it to stop whenever i stop holding left click. https://pastebin.com/SPpw0Qjf is the full code

Comment: The length of the comment is limited, see [link](https://pastebin.com/UrCA5gUv) for details

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the inner-most `while` loop. It is an infinite loop that is broken only by pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd>. The middle `while` loop is all you need, it stops when the left mouse button is released.

```
while (true)
{
  //toggles it on and off
  if (GetAsyncKeyState('U') & 1)
    bClick = !bClick;
  if (bClick)
  {
    while (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LBUTTON) < 0)
    {
       INPUT input[2] = {};

       input[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
       input[0].mi.dx = x;
       input[0].mi.dy = y;
       input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;

       input[1] = input[0];
       input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;

       SendInput(2, input, sizeof(INPUT));

       std::cout << "Clicked ";
       std::cout << clicks++;
       std::cout << " times \n";
       Sleep(1000 / cps);
       if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE))
       {
         break;
       }
    }
  }
}
```